# Android SDK Google Play Services 7.8.99 -- Not being updated in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android

I have a Boost ZTE that was recently updated to Google Play Services 7.8.99.  In my Android SDK environment I have Google Play Services 7.8.55 (API level 26).  I am not able to find 7.8.99 from the SDK Manager and it shows no updates.  My apps are not working because of the incompatibility between the two.  FYI, in my build.gradle I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
}
```

Does anyone have information on how to get 7.8.99 in the Android SDK?

Comment: "My apps are not working because of the incompatibility between the two" -- what are the specific symptoms? Also, FWIW, I see a `7.8.0` in `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services`, but I don't see a `.55`, let alone a `.99`. Where and how are you determining that you have `7.8.55`?

Comment: The latest version I see in my SDK manager is 7.8.95.000. For one, you should not be using a wildcard ( `+` sign) for that dependency. You should depend on a version of Play Service that you know to be fully (or near fully) rolled out.

Comment: I tried both with and without the wildcard and get the same results.  The error is here.

Comment: Sorry, hit return ...I get an error that the client version is Google Play Services 789500 and the package version is 78999034.  This is from the stack trace in the Android Window on Studio.  I was just using the upgrade services on my Boost device and it got that version.  Perhaps your point is to find a way on the device to back off to 7.8.55 ...

Comment: You can use 7.8.0 library with 7.8.+ Google Play services app on your phone. That's the point: You can use old library and it will work as the app upgrades. So include older, definitive version of the library in your project.

Comment: Hi.  I have tried using a compile dependency of 7.8.0.  I continue to get the same error ... that the client is 789500 and the the package on the device is 7899034 so I am not sure what you mean by your comment.  Its certainly not working for my combination of play-services and device.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an answer or not.  But I ended up putting more traces and debugging in my code and I got it to at least start the location service by putting a while loop in waiting for the play services to connect and checking isConnected() status.  So the different levels of play services warning was not the issue and the IllegalStateException was because the play services was taking a long time to connect.